# Утечка памяти в проекте

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

у меня mfc проект, в VisualStudio в настройках проекта стояла надстройка Common Language Runtime Support (/clr) как я понимаю это среда .Net у которой был сборщик мусора, однако появилась задача отключить его(No Common Language Runtime Support), и теперь при закрытии программы у меня утечка на 36 Байт, я удалил полностью код, в main функции у меня просто стоит return FALSE; И все равно утекает, подскажите кто съедает память в таком случае?

Comment: Что вам сообщило, что есть утечка?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{155} normal block at 0x00D9FE58, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <| D     > 7C B9 44 0F 00 00 00 00 
{154} normal block at 0x00D85310, 28 bytes long.
 Data: < S   S   S      > 10 53 D8 00 10 53 D8 00 10 53 D8 00 01 01 CD CD 
Object dump complete.

Comment: @Abyx Серьезно? "я удалил полностью код, в main функции у меня просто стоит return FALSE", у меня ни одного выделения памяти нет